# Split string with PowerShell and do something with each token

Tags: string, powershell, tokenize

I want to split each line of a pipe on spaces, and then print each token on its own line.

I realise that I can get this result using:

```
(cat someFileInsteadOfAPipe).split(" ")
```

But I want more flexibility. I want to be able to do just about anything with each token. (I used to use [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) on Unix, and I'm trying to get the same functionality.)

I currently have:

```
echo "Once upon a time there were three little pigs" | %{$data = $_.split(" "); Write-Output "$($data[0]) and whatever I want to output with it"}
```

Which, obviously, only prints the first token. Is there a way for me to for-each over the tokens, printing each in turn?

Also, the `%{$data = $_.split(" "); Write-Output "$($data[0])"}` part I got from a blog, and I really don't understand what I'm doing or how the syntax works.

I want to google for it, but I don't know what to call it. Please help me out with a word or two to Google, or a link explaining to me what the `%` and all the `$` symbols do, as well as the significance of the opening and closing brackets.

I realise I can't actually use `(cat someFileInsteadOfAPipe).split(" ")`, since the file (or preferable incoming pipe) contains more than one line.

Regarding some of the answers:

If you are using [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) to filter the output before tokenizing, you need to keep in mind that the output of the `Select-String` command is not a collection of strings, but a collection of `MatchInfo` objects. To get to the string you want to split, you need to access the `Line` property of the `MatchInfo` object, like so:

```
cat someFile | Select-String "keywordFoo" | %{$_.Line.Split(" ")}
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
"Once upon a time there were three little pigs".Split(" ") | ForEach {
    "$_ is a token"
 }
```

The key is `$_`, which stands for the current variable in the pipeline.

About the code you found online:

`%` is an alias for [`ForEach-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx). Anything enclosed inside the brackets is run once for each object it receives. In this case, it's only running once, because you're sending it a single string.

`$_.Split(" ")` is taking the current variable and splitting it on spaces. The current variable will be whatever is currently being looped over by `ForEach`.

Comment: aaaah, thanks for the edit. Knowing that `%` is short for `foreach-object` means I can do this for multiple lines: `cat .\tmp.txt | %{$_.Split(" ")} | %{Write-Output "$($_) hello"}` Problem solved.

Comment: Perfect! Glad I could help. The last part of your command could actually just be `"$_ hello"`. You only need to use the $($variable) notation if you're trying to expand the value of an object's property inside a string. For example `"My last name is $($person.surname)."` Or the output of a cmdlet's method: `"Tomorrow's date is $((Get-Date).AddDays(1))"`.

Comment: Just a note: As of PowerShell v2 there is a `-split` operator which can be used to split on whitespace in general (`-split $foo`) or analogous to `.Split(' ')`: `$foo -split ' '`.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Justus Grunow's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348779/45375):

- As [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348779/45375) notes in a comment, PowerShell has a powerful, regex-based [`-split` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split).

  - **In its *unary* form (`-split '...'`), `-split` behaves like `awk`'s default field splitting**, which means that:

    - Leading and trailing whitespace is ignored.
    - Any *run* of whitespace (e.g., *multiple* adjacent spaces) is treated as a *single* separator.
- In **PowerShell v4+** an expression-based - and therefore faster - **alternative to the [`ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) became available: the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)**, (alongside the [`.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where), a more powerful, expression-based alternative to [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)).

Here's a solution based on these features:

```bash
PS> (-split '   One      for the money   ').ForEach({ "token: [$_]" })
token: [One]
token: [for]
token: [the]
token: [money]
```

Note that the leading and trailing whitespace was ignored, and that the multiple spaces between `One` and `for` were treated as a single separator.

Answer (score 3):

-split outputs an array, and you can save it to a variable like this:

```
$a = -split 'Once  upon    a     time'
$a[0]

Once
```

Another cute thing, you can have arrays on both sides of an assignment statement:

```
$a,$b,$c = -split 'Once  upon    a'
$c

a
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish this is a combination of Justus Thane's and mklement0's answers.  It doesn't make sense to do it this way when you look at a one liner example, but when you're trying to mass-edit a file or a bunch of filenames it comes in pretty handy:

```
$test = '   One      for the money   '
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$($test.split(' ',$option)).foreach{$_}
```

This will come out as:

```
One
for
the
money
```

Comment: I keep finding that I get the wrong number when using a plain text file with one line containing one computer name (hostname) and one blank line.

`$counterTotal = $($computers.Split(" ").count)` gives me exactly what I want.  Thanks for the inspiration @s31064