# How to split a string content into an array of strings in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, arrays, string, powershell

I have a string that has email addresses separated by semi-colon:

```
$address = "foo@bar.com; boo@bar.com; zoo@bar.com"
```

How can I split this into an array of strings that would result as the following?

```
[string[]]$recipients = "foo@bar.com", "boo@bar.com", "zoo@bar.com"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string with PowerShell and do something with each token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348506/split-string-with-powershell-and-do-something-with-each-token)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As of PowerShell 2, simple:

```
$recipients = $addresses -split "; "
```

Note that the right hand side is actually a case-insensitive [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), not a simple match. Use `csplit` to force case-sensitivity. See *[about_Split](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx)* for more details.

Answer (score 12):

```
[string[]]$recipients = $address.Split('; ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 10):

Remove the spaces from the original string and split on semicolon

```
$address = "foo@bar.com; boo@bar.com; zoo@bar.com"
$addresses = $address.replace(' ','').split(';')
```

Or all in one line:

```
$addresses = "foo@bar.com; boo@bar.com; zoo@bar.com".replace(' ','').split(';')
```

`$addresses` becomes:

```
@('foo@bar.com','boo@bar.com','zoo@bar.com')
```