# How to split string to an array of strings without multiple spaces

Tags: .net, powershell, split, powershell-2.0

I have string `$x` from a TextBox:
[image]

I want to split this string to an array of strings without the '*'.

I run:    `$a = $x.Split("*")` but I received double spaces in the "7-zip":
[image]

**Suggestion 1:**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435240/how-to-split-string-by-string-in-powershell) they suggested to user `-split` **but** when using it I received a string (array of **chars**), not an array of strings:
[image]

**Suggestion 2:**
In [this](http://www.jbmurphy.com/2011/11/18/powershell-code-to-split-a-space-delimited-string-with-double-spaces/) blog and on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028419/how-to-split-a-string-content-into-an-array-of-strings-in-powershell) question they suggested to use `[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntrie` + `foreach` (in the blog) in order to parse the un-wanted spaces.
I tried:

```
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
 $b = $x.Split("*", $option) |foreach {
    $_.Split(" ", $option)
}
```

**But** it didn't help:
[image]

How can I split a string to an array of strings separated by "*" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found out, you can remove the "blank" entry after the last occurrence of `*` with `[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Now, all you need to do to remove unwanted space around the words, is to call `Trim()`:

```
$x = @"
ccleaner*
7-zip*
"@

$Words = $x.Split('*',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim()
}

PS C:\> $Words[0]
ccleaner
PS C:\> $Words[0]
7-zip
PS C:\>
```

---

You can also use `-split` (you only need a single `\` to escape `*`) and then filter out empty entries with `Where-Object`:

```
"a*b* *c" -split "\*" | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "^\s+$" }| ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
```

or the other way around (use `Where-Object` after removing whitespace):

```
"a*b* *c" -split "\*" | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Where-Object { $_ }
```

---

You could also use `-replace` to remove leading and trailing whitespace (basically, the regex version of `Trim()`):

```
" a b " -replace "^\s+|\s+$",""
# results in "a b"
```

Comment: Make the regular expression ``\*`n?`` and you don't need the extra `Trim()` call.