# How to input two variables into one command

Tags: powershell, variables, user-input

I am stuck at this:
The user needs to input two computer names and i don't know how to transfer them into one input (maybe i'm asking it wrong) but here is the code

```
elseif ($usersinput -eq 2) 
{
    $pingingtwopcs = Read-Host -Prompt "what are the names of the pc that >you want to ping? (please enter pc names in the next order with comma : >pc1,pc2)"
    foreach ($pcs in $pingingtwopcs)
    {
        Test-Connection -computername $pcs -Count 1
    }
}
```

Please don't provide the solution, if it is possible please direct me so I'll figure it out by my self.

Comment: `Read-Host` will return a string, not two variables. So you have to [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617758/splitting-a-string-into-separate-variables) that string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
$pingingtwopcs = (Read-Host -Prompt "what are the names of the pc that >you want to ping? (please enter pc names in the next order with comma : >pc1,pc2)").split(',') | ForEach-Object {$_.trim()}
```

The above line will accept two values, separated by a `comma`, in a single go. As `Read-Host` accepts the input in a `String` format, you will have to use the `Split()` method to separate them and store it in `$pingingtwopcs`. The `Trim()` method will remove any extra space which has been entered during input.

Comment: so it should look like that :

 $pingingtwopcs = (Read-Host -Prompt "what are the names of the pc that you want to ping? (please enter pc names in the next order with comma : >pc1,pc2)").split(',') | ForEach-Object {$_.trim()}

           foreach ($computer in $pingingtwopcs) {

          Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1


soryy that it's written that way from some reason the ">" sign not working :\


It's working ~!!@!@#!#@!!!!

so what did the trick?

this thing ".split(',')"?

Comment: The `>` sign is not working?
What are you expecting it to do? Anyways it is enclosed within `double quotes` and will only be displayed on screen and nothing else. You have to enter two PC names separated by a `comma` when the prompt asks you to do so!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `Read-Host`, this is bad design and does not allow for automation.
Instead let the user propvide the ComputerName(s) either as a string an array.

```
function Write-ComputerName([System.Array]$ComputerName) {
    foreach($oneComputerName in $ComputerName){
        Write-Output $oneComputerName
    }
}
```

Then a user can either pass in one or multiple ones:

```
Write-ComputerName 'Bob'
Write-ComputerName @('Bob','Alice')
```

If you still need to do custom logic based on the number of ComputerNames, then you can use `$ComputerName.Count` in your function.

Comment: but then it'll become a function and will behave like a cmdlet, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. But this was one of the main points of PowerShell to have a common, well defined user interface without re-inventing basic parameter parsing/retrieving logic.

Comment: my friend i'm in power shell only 3 weeks (this is the end of the third) let me do my mistakes and do stuff as i understand :) after i will get used to it, i promise you that things will look much better :)

Thanks for your help :)