# Convertfrom-string removes leading zeros

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

Im having a problem with the Convertfrom-String cmdlet

```
$value = 'something:009' 
$value | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ':'
```

Output:

```
P1        P2
--        --
something  9
```

The output i want is

```
P1        P2
--        --
something  009
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cmdlet seems to do some automatic parsing, and `009` becomes a byte. Would `$value -split ':'` do?

Comment: You could use the [template variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-String?view=powershell-5.1) and assign types in the template (example 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest avoiding [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1) altogether - it performs type conversions that you cannot control when you use `-Delimiter`, as you've experienced, and its example-driven template-based parsing is awkward.

<sup>On a side note: `ConvertFrom-String` is not available in the cross-platform [PowerShell *Core* edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).</sup>

In your simple case, use `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead:

```
$value = 'something:009' 
$value | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Header P1, P2
```

`ConvertFrom-Csv` reads all values as strings, as-is (with string input; enclosing double quotes around field values are removed).

Answer (score 0):

mklement0 propose the best solution. You can do it too :

Solution 1 : with a simple split (not you can split with regex too)

```
$value = 'something:009' 
$values=$value -split ':'

[pscustomobject]@{
Val1=$values[0]
Val2=$values[1]
}
```

Solution 2 : with ConvertFrom-String and a Template

```
$template=@"
{{Val1:Abc123}:{Val2:1}}
"@

$value = 'something:009' 
$value | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
```

Comment: Good to see a working example with a template, though your specific example field values are confusing: the first field in the input doesn't have digits, and using `1` as the example value for the 2nd one suggests a number (or, if interpreted as a string, in no obvious way matches `009` other than being _composed of_ digits), which is specifically _not_ desired here. The command does work, however - which I find puzzling, and is one of the reasons I stay away from `ConvertFrom-String`. Note that simply using `x` as the example values would suffice in this case: `{{Val1:x}:{Val2:x}}`.