# Change 3 characters in a list of users DisplayName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to change 3 characters for a list of users. all these users have a bit appended on their DisplayName (ABcD-somthing) i want to change that something to (ABcD-ICC)
I was going to use

`Set-aduser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{DisplayName="$_.Surname, $_.GivenName (ABcD-ICC)"}`

But the only thing I would be changing is the ICC at the very end. is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: show example of current name and expected please.

Comment: Look at how to split a string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617758/splitting-a-string-into-separate-variables

Comment: `-Replace @{DisplayName=$_.DisplayName -replace 'ICC\)$','something)'}`?

Comment: So a current name might be: lastname, firstname (ABcD-EFG) I want to make it lastname, firstname (ABcD-HIJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-replace` operator for this and make it vary as necessary:

```
# Replaces three characters before a final character of )
$replace = 'ICC'
Set-aduser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{DisplayName=$_.DisplayName -replace '.{3}(?=\)$)',$replace}
```

**Explanation:**

`-replace` uses regex matching and replaces the match with a replacement string. The replacement string can be a literal string, contain variables, or capture groups matched by the regex portion.

`.` is any single character. `{3}` matches exactly three times. `(?=)` is a positive lookahead assertion, which the means the future characters match what is inside from the current position. Lookahead allows for a match that isn't captured and therefore it is not output and not replaced. `$` means the end of the string. `\)` is backslash escaping a literal `)`. Since `(` and `)` have special meaning in regex, they must be escaped.

---

Sometimes you may not know the last character. In that case, you can use the following to replace the three characters before a final arbitrary characters:

```
$replace = 'ICC'
Set-aduser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{DisplayName=$_.DisplayName -replace '.{3}(?=.$)',$replace}
```

---

If you wanted to replace the final three characters regardless of their value, you can do the following:

```
$replace = 'ICC'
Set-aduser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{DisplayName=$_.DisplayName -replace '.{3}$',$replace}
```

---

If you wanted to replace the final three consecutive alpha characters even if they are far from the end of the string, you can do:

```
$replace = 'ICC'
Set-aduser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{DisplayName=$_.DisplayName -replace '[a-z]{3}(?=[^a-z]*$)',$replace}
```