# How is the regex split different or distinct from string split?

Tags: arrays, string, function, powershell, operators

In [using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68438372/4531180) the `split` operator, as:

```
**********************
PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20210719105630
Username: gondor\nicholas
RunAs User: gondor\nicholas
Configuration Name: 
Machine: gondor (Unix 5.8.0.59)
Host Application: /snap/powershell/160/opt/powershell/pwsh.dll
Process ID: 16273
PSVersion: 7.1.3
PSEdition: Core
GitCommitId: 7.1.3
OS: Linux 5.8.0-59-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 00:46:01 UTC 2021
Platform: Unix
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.10032.0, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 7.0.0, 7.1.3
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
**********************
Transcript started, output file is strings.txt
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $string = "b1i9r8t7h"  
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array = $string -split "\d"
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array
b
i
r
t
h
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array = $string -split "\D"
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array

1
9
8
7

PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array = $string.split("\D")
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array
b1i9r8t7h
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array = $string.split("\d")
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> $array
b1i9r8t7h
PS /home/nicholas/power_shell> Stop-Transcript
**********************
PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20210719105811
**********************
```

what is the result of using the dot operator above?  Does it do anything?  Nothing?  Seems it should do something or return an error.

**How is the function distinguished from the operator?**

see also:

https://www.sqlshack.com/powershell-split-a-string-into-an-array/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0

---

*On a side note, how are the help files for the operator and the function accessed from the `REPL` console?*

Comment: The `.Split(..)` string method will split on a delimiter it doesn't work on regular expressions such as `\D` or `\d`. The `-split` operator on the other hand will allow you to split using `regex`, similar to `[regex]::Split(..)`. `[regex]::Split('b1i9r8t7h','\D')` and `'b1i9r8t7h' -split '\D'` will give you the results you expect.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon this should be an answer. To see more about the operator, check out `about_split`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I know, I didn't post it as answer because of OP's last question "_how are the help files for the operator and the function accessed from the REPL console_" which I'm not sure how to answer but if OP considers I can post my comment as an answer I will do so.

Comment: I added the help file links, but, yes @SantiagoSquarzon the question is how are these things differentiated.

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) to the linked duplicates answers all questions.

Answer (score 0):

Help files say:

> Remarks
>
> The Regex.Split methods are similar to the String.Split(Char[])
> method, except that Regex.Split splits the string at a delimiter
> determined by a regular expression instead of a set of characters.

which is all fine and good.

Would welcome a more in depth answer.