Powershell Arg broke after submit from PHP
Until recently my PHP script calling a Powershell script with arguments was working fine, but now the string supposedly is in this format @("grp1","grp2") on the Powershell side it is now grp1 grp2
The echo on PHP's side before submission to Powershell is @(\"grp1\",\"grp2\")
The $_POST["groups"] is an array.
Here is my PHP code:
<?php

$ADJoinGroups = "C:\Scripts\AD_Joingrps.ps1";

$entity = $_POST["entity"];
$fName = $_POST["fName"];
$lName = $_POST["lName"];
$desc = $_POST["description"];
$password = "#####";

$groups = '@(\"'.implode('\",\"',$_POST["groups"]).'\")';

echo '<pre>'; print_r($groups); echo '</pre>';

if (isset($_POST['cGrps'])) {
$res1 = shell_exec("powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command $ADJoinGroups $fName $lName $groups 2>&1");
echo $res1;
}

?>

The Powershell script looks as follows:
###### Args ######
$fName = $args[0];
$lName = $args[1];
$groups = $args[2];

Write-output $groups;

Does anyone know why this happens? And, do you have a way to revert it to @("grp1","grp2") from grp1 grp2 in Powershell?
Many thanks :)

probably caused by passing backslashes in the $groups variable?

Nope I added them to prevent the quotation marks to be removed in the process (escape char)

Can't you pass your groups another way? For instance grp1/grp2?

If you print out the full commandline string, does that look correct ?

@Olivier powershell is expecting an array @("","","") since I'm doing a loop to add many groups : foreach ($group in $using:groups)
{
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "$group" -Members "$using:SamAccountName"
}

I'm not familiar with PowerShell, but can't you split the string grp1/grp2 to create an array from it?

In powershell I only get the first groupname when testing,  others are silently discarded. Please provide suitable test parameters to help emulate what you are actually passing in as POST variables

Splitting a string is easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617758/splitting-a-string-into-separate-variables

@ProfessorAbronsius The initial $_POST=["groups"] is an array like this Array
(
[0] => grp1
[1] => grp2
)

@Olivier yes that's what I think I need to do now, make the array on powershell side splitting my groups so I get the right format

I found that wrapping the $groups portion of the commandline in double quotes with individual groups within single quotes is OK

Thanks @Professor Abronsius you made me on the right path. Single quotes around my $groups made it
shell_exec("powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command $ADJoinGroups $fName $lName '$groups' 2>&1");```


The test scripts I ran to emulate the original script with the difference of the groups portion of the commandline string being enclosed within double quotes and group names within single quotes.
<?php

    $ADJoinGroups = "C:\data\Archives\Scripts\Powershell\AD_Joingrps.ps1";
    
    $_POST["entity"]='Corporate Chief';
    $_POST["description"]='Something...or...other';
    $_POST["fName"]='John';
    $_POST["lName"]='Smith';
    $_POST['groups']=array( 'printusers', 'powerusers', 'cor-c-dc-telstar1', 'cor-c-dc-frontline' );
    
    
    $entity = $_POST["entity"];
    $fName = $_POST["fName"];
    $lName = $_POST["lName"];
    $desc = $_POST["description"];
    $password = "#####";
    
    # individual groups within single quotes
    $groups=sprintf( "@('%s')", implode( "','", $_POST['groups'] ) );
    
    # entire groups portion within double-quotes
    $cmd=sprintf('powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command %s %s %s "%s" 2>&1', $ADJoinGroups, $fName, $lName, $groups );
    $res=shell_exec( $cmd );
    
    
    
    printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $res,true ) );

?>

Powershell test script:
function adUserGroups{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $fName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $lName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Array] $groups
    )
    Write-output $fName, $lName;
    
    foreach( $group in $groups ){
        write-output "Add to Group->$group"
    }
    
}

adUserGroups -fName ($args[0]) -lName ($args[1]) -groups ($args[2])

Output in browser:
John
Smith
Add to Group->printusers
Add to Group->powerusers
Add to Group->cor-c-dc-telstar1
Add to Group->cor-c-dc-frontline

